# Python Class Inheritance: How to initialize a subclass with values not in the parent class

Tags: python, class, python-2.7, inheritance

I'm trying to learn more about classes and OOP.

How can I have my `Person` class initialize with all the values of `Entity` but also with a value that may not be contained in the `Entity` class?

For example, both `Person` and `Spirit` inherit from `Entity`. However, only a `Person` would have a `gender`. How can I have `Person` initialize with `gender` as well?

After that, would I still be able to create an instance of `Person` and call `describe()` in the same way I've done below?

```python
class Entity(object):

    def __init__(self, state, name, age):
        self.state = state
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

class Person(Entity):

    def describe(self):
        print "Identification: %s, %s, %s." % (self.state, self.name, self.age)

class Spirit(Entity):
    pass  # for now

steve = Person("human", "Steve", "23" # can I then list gender here?)
steve.describe()
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Create a custom initializer on the sub-class and then call the parent class's initializer via `super`:

```
class Person(Entity):
    def __init__(self, state, name, age, gender):
        self.gender = gender
        super(Person, self).__init__(state, name, age)
```

Answer (score 8):

Transitionally, it looks like versions of Py 3.x (not sure which ones) allow this terse version of `super()`:

```
def __init__(self, state, name, age, gender):
        self.gender = gender
        # Prototype initialization 3.x:
        super().__init__(state, name, age)
```

Been experimenting with SQLAlchemy models using dataclasses, so when I zipped on by looking at all things Python inheritance, I felt this might extend the answer:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Entity():
    state: str
    name: str
    age: int

@dataclass
class Person(Entity):
    gender: str

    def describe(self):
        print("State: {state}, Name: {name}, Age: {age}, Gender: {gender}"
            .format(state=self.state, name=self.name, age=self.age, gender=self.gender))

man = Person("human", "humanname", 21, "cisgendered")

man.describe()
```