# Class Inheritance Problems in Python

Tags: python, inheritance, subclassing

I'm writing a program that allows a user to search an API for media information and then divided them into Songs and Movies. I'm using classes to do this and have a parent class (Media) and two child classes (Song, Movie). My Media class works great when I search the API and I get all the information I want. However, when I try to create Song or Movie instances, the information won't inherit from the Media class (I get an error that the subclass is missing positional arguments) and I can't figure out why. Any help would be great!

```
class Media:
    def __init__(self, title="No Title", author="No Author", release_year="No Release Year", url="No URL", json=None):
        if json==None:
            self.title = title
            self.author = author
            self.release_year = release_year
            self.url = url
        else:
            if 'trackName' in json.keys():
                self.title = json['trackName']
            else:
                self.title = json['collectionName']
            self.author = json['artistName']
            self.release_year = json['releaseDate'][:4]
            if 'trackViewUrl' in json.keys():
                self.url = json['trackViewUrl']
            elif 'collectionViewUrl' in json.keys():
                self.url = json['collectionViewUrl']
            else:
                self.url = None

    def info(self):
        return f"{self.title} by {self.author} ({self.release_year})"

    def length(self):
        return 0


class Song(Media):
    def __init__(self, t, a, r_y, u, json=None, album="No Album", genre="No Genre", track_length=0):
        super().__init__(t,a, r_y, u)
        if json==None:
            self.album = album
            self.genre = genre
            self.track_length = track_length
        else:
            self.album = json['collectionName']
            self.genre = json['primaryGenreName']
            self.track_length = json['trackTimeMillis']

    def info(self):
        return f"{self.title} by {self.author} ({self.release_year}) [{self.genre}]"

    def length(self):
        length_in_secs = self.track_length / 1000
        return round(length_in_secs)


class Movie(Media):
    def __init__(self, t, a, r_y, u, json=None, rating="No Rating", movie_length=0):
        super().__init__(t, a, r_y, u)
        if json==None:
            self.rating = rating
            self.movie_length = movie_length
        else:
            self.rating = json['contentAdvisoryRating']
            self.movie_length = json['trackTimeMillis']

    def info(self):
        return f"{self.title} by {self.author} ({self.release_year}) [{self.rating}]"

    def length(self):
        length_in_mins = self.movie_length / 60000
        return round(length_in_mins)
```

Comment: Try replace  ```super().__init__(t,a, r_y, u)``` with  ```Media.__init__(self,t,a,r_y,u)```

Comment: @InhirCode There's no reason to do that. What we need is a reproducible example.

Comment: @Jeffrey in simple words, as your subclass (say `Movie`) suggests, you have to provide explicitly the positional args namely, `t`, `a` etc. while creating an instance of the same.

Comment: @ApuCoder is there no way to initialize the subclasses so that they use whatever values are decided on in the base class (whether it's the default values or the information pulled from a json object)?

Comment: @Jeffrey could you please clarify the following in detail - *'initialize the subclasses so that they use whatever values are decided on in the base class (whether it's the default values...'*.

Comment: @ApuCoder I actually ended up figuring out my problem. In my parent class I never initialized the self.json attribute so my super().init(t, a, r_y, u, json) wasn't inheriting the json information from the parent class. Once I fixed that, I was able to put the default values into the parameters for the subclasses without it overriding the json info I put in.

Comment: If you did mean by `t`, `a` etc. the kwargs already introduced at base class, you don't have to mention those again in subclasses.

Comment: @ApuCoder are you sureabout your latter comment, seems the opposite of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23452230/python-class-inheritance-how-to-initialize-a-subclass-with-values-not-in-the-pa

Comment: @pippo1980 I couldn't find any adverse comment/answer to what I wanted to say in the post you mentioned.

Comment: So probably I didnt get the meanjng of: If you did mean by t, a etc. the kwargs already introduced at base class, you don't have to mention those again in subclasses. – .  About what kind of mention you are referring here ?

Comment: @pippo1980 I clarify that in answer.

Answer (score 2):

First, let's simplify the problem. Ignore JSON, and assume all arguments are required (i.e., no dummy defaults like "No title").

```
class Media:
    def __init__(self, *, title, author, release_year, url, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.title = title
        self.author = author
        self.release_year = release_year
        self.url = url

    def info(self):
        return f"{self.title} by {self.author} ({self.release_year})"

    def length(self):
        return 0


class Song(Media):
    def __init__(self, *, album, genre, track_length, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.album = album
        self.genre = genre
        self.track_length = track_length

    def info(self):
        return super().info() + f" [{self.genre}]"

    def length(self):
        length_in_secs = self.track_length / 1000
        return round(length_in_secs)


class Movie(Media):
    def __init__(self, *, rating, movie_length, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.rating = rating
        self.movie_length = movie_length

    def info(self):
        return super().info() + f" [{self.rating}]"

    def length(self):
        length_in_mins = self.movie_length / 60000
        return round(length_in_mins)

song = Song(title="...", author="...", release_year="...", url="...", album="...", genre="...", track_length="...")
```

The use of keywords arguments and `super` are as recommended in [Python's `super()` considered super!](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/). Further, each `info` method is defined in terms of the parent's `info` method, in order to reduce duplicate code.

---

Now, how do we deal with JSON? Ideally, we'd like to define a single class method that extracts values from the `dict` decoded from JSON and use those values to create an instance. For example,

```
class Media:
    ...

    @classmethod
    def from_json(cls, json):
        if 'trackName' in json:
            title = json['trackName']
        else:
            title = json['collectionName']
        author = json['artistName']
        release_year = json['releaseDate'][:4]
        if 'trackViewUrl' in json:
            url = json['trackViewUrl']
        elif 'collectionViewUrl' in json.keys():
            url = json['collectionViewUrl']
        else:
            url = None
        return cls(title=title, author=author, release_year=release_year, url=url)
```

However, we'd also like to build up `Song.from_json` and `Movie.from_json` in terms of `Media.from_json`, but it's not obvious how to do that.

```
class Song:
    ...
    @classmethod
    def from_json(cls, json):
        obj = super().from_json(json)
```

`Media.from_json` attempts to return an instance of `Song`, but it doesn't know how to get the required arguments to do so.

Instead, we'll define *two* class methods. One takes care of processing the JSON into an appropriate `dict`, the other simply calls `cls` using that `dict`.

```
class Media:
    ...

    @classmethod
    def _gather_arguments(cls, json):
        d = {}
        if 'trackName' in json:
            d['title'] = json['trackName']
        else:
            d['title'] = json['collectionName']
        d['author'] = json['artistName']
        d['release_year'] = json['releaseDate'][:4]
        if 'trackViewUrl' in json:
            d['url'] = json['trackViewUrl']
        elif 'collectionViewUrl' in json.keys():
            d['url'] = json['collectionViewUrl']
        else:
            d['url'] = None

        return d

    @classmethod
    def from_json(cls, json):
        d = cls._gather_arguments(json)
        return cls(**d)
```

Now for our two subclasses, we don't need to touch `from_json` at all: it already does everything we need it to do. All we need to do is to override `_gather_arguments` to add our additional values to whatever `Media._gather_arguments` returns.

```
class Song(Media):
    ...

    @classmethod
    def _gather_arguments(cls, json):
        d = super()._gather_arguments(json)
        d['album'] = json['collectionName']
        d['genre'] = json['primaryGenreName']
        d['track_length'] = json['trackTimeMillis']
        return d
```

and

```
class Movie(Media):
    ...

    @classmethod
    def _gather_arguments(cls, json):
        d = super()._gather_arguments(json)
        d['rating'] = json['contentAdvisoryRating']
        d['movie_length'] = json['trackTimeMillis']
        return d
```

Comment: Though it deals with 'kwd_only_arg' not optional/kwargs (as in the OP's post), I found it more suitable than that of mine (because of the implementation with `classmethod`). Upvoted.

Comment: @ApuCoder, sorry to bother, but you answed before to me.  Here if I try pippo = Movie('titleeee','authorrrrrrrrr',1900, 'www.pippo.com')  [No keyword] I get --> pippo error : __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 5 were given, the '1 positional argument' would be 'self' ??

Comment: Read the linked article, which presents an argument for using keyword arguments rather than positional arguments in this case.

Answer (score 1):

> My Media class works great when...I want.

When you create an instance of `Media` class say, `med = Media()` it will work well even without any args as all its args are kwargs (or optional args). But,

> However, when I try to create Song or Movie instances...

This will not 'cause in the constructor of a subclass of `Media` say, `Movie` you did :

```py
    def __init__(self, t, a, r_y, u, json=None, rating="No Rating", movie_length=0):
        super().__init__(t, a, r_y, u)
```

which takes some positional args `t`, `a` etc. So when you create an instance of this subclass say `mov = Movie()` it will throw a `TypeError`.

So the one way you can fix this is, obviously provide those positional args in each instances of `Movie` class.

The other way (and here **I assume that you wanted to mean `title` by `t`; `author` by `a`; `release_year` by `r_y` and `url` by `u`**) is make them all kwargs.

So first in your base class,

```py
class Media:
    def __init__(self, title="No Title", author="No Author", release_year="No Release Year", url="No URL", json=None, **kwargs):
        self.json = json # Store it here.
        if self.json is None: # Better suited than '=='.
            self.title = title
            self.author = author
            self.release_year = release_year
            self.url = url
        else:
            ...
```

With `**kwargs` you are actually instructing your base class `Media` that it (or/and its subclasses) can have arbitrary no. of keyword-arguments.

Using this and `super` appropriately in any of your subclass(es) you will be able to incorporate new kwargs (apart from the defined ones in the base class, actually now you need not to mention them again).

Now in a subclass say `Movie` you can just define new kwargs as,

```py
class Movie(Media):
    def __init__(self, rating="No Rating", movie_length=0, **kwargs):
        # Now call super and provide only the new ones. With an extra '**kwargs' you keep the consistency with the base class.
        super().__init__(rating="No Rating", movie_length=0, **kwargs)
        if self.json is None:
            self.rating = rating
            self.movie_length = movie_length
        else:
            ...
```

With this change(s) the following should work as expected,

```py
Mov = Movie()
print(Mov.title)
print(Mov.info())
```